# How to debug bootloader code running on RAM for powerPC

Tags: debugging, ram, bootloader, powerpc, mpc

I'm developing a bootloader for the MPC5748G in C.

The bootloader will be running on RAM so i want to know how can i debug the bootloader code running on the MPC Target.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without further information on the platform you are using, the general guideline is that you compile your Bootloader software with Debug symbols, and once loaded, start a debugging session which should be configured to **attach** to the process (instead of the classical load-then-break-at-main). Then, hitting pause should interrupt the target, and from here on it is a normal debugging session.